# SQL Server 2005 dependency cache without asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know a good online resource about using SQL Server 2005 dependency cache *without* asp.net (it's actually a console app).  Using c# 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the base system that makes working with it plug and play like ASP.NET has. However, the Enterprise Library has the Caching Application Block which works with any type of application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203226.aspx